# PostgreSQL query to list all table names?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, information-schema

Is there any query available to list all tables in my Postgres DB.

I tried out one query like:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
                      WHERE table_schema='public'
```

But this query returns views also.

How can i get only table names only, not views?

Answer (score 461):

What bout this query (based on the description from [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-tables.html))?

```sql
SELECT table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema='public'
   AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Comment: What is a table type?

Comment: table_type from the manual: Type of the table: BASE TABLE for a persistent base table (the normal table type), VIEW for a view, FOREIGN for a foreign table, or LOCAL TEMPORARY for a temporary table

Answer (score 51):

If you want list of database

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;
```

If you want list of tables from current pg installation of all databases

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY table_schema,table_name;
```

Comment: At least in Postgres 9.5, that's not true. I've got 3 databases in one cluster, and this is only returning tables from the current database.

Comment: Documentation says only the current one: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/infoschema-tables.html "table_catalog sql_identifier Name of the database that contains the table (always the current database)"

Answer (score 35):

Open up the postgres terminal with the databse you would like:

```
psql dbname (run this line in a terminal)
```

then, run this command in the postgres environment

```
\d
```

This will describe all tables by name. Basically a list of tables by name ascending.

Then you can try this to describe a table by fields:

```
\d tablename.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @wingedpanther  how to?  there are a `\d` option to list  *only* all tables, with no index, no seq, ...?

Comment: Is ```\dt``` not there for this?

Comment: In my experience, wherever I needed to look for table list it was always because I wanted to see if a table exists. Or if do I have a table say for which "contact information" so may I want see all table with "contact" in the name which might come at the beginning, middle, end , anywhere or be just "contact" so I always found schema-vele query to be helpful in that case i.e. SELECT table_name  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'   AND table_type='BASE TABLE' and table_name like '%contact%; Rather than going through the list of tables in ascending order.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
```

this one works!

Comment: I don't think we need `table_type='BASE TABLE'`.  Perhaps I am wrong, could you please elaborate?

Comment: sometimes is useful filtering current connected DB
adding: *and table_catalog = current_database()*

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema='public';
```

For MySQL you would need table_schema='dbName' and for MSSQL remove that condition.

Notice that "only those tables and views are shown that the current user has access to". Also, if you have access to many databases and want to limit the result to a certain database, you can achieve that by adding condition AND table_catalog='yourDatabase' (in PostgreSQL).

If you'd also like to get rid of the header showing row names and footer showing row count, you could either start the psql with command line option -t (short for --tuples-only) or you can toggle the setting in psql's command line by \t (short for \pset tuples_only). This could be useful for example when piping output to another command with \g [ |command ].

Answer (score 10):

How about giving just `\dt` in `psql`? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html.

Comment: Yes, this gives the list of `tables` within the connected `database`, not the content of a particular `table` within the database.  This is the answer to the question asked here.

Answer (score 9):

```
select 
 relname as table 
from 
 pg_stat_user_tables 
where schemaname = 'public'
```

- This will not work if [**track_activities**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html) is disabled

---

```
select 
  tablename as table 
from 
  pg_tables  
where schemaname = 'public'
```

- Read more about [**pg_tables**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/view-pg-tables.html)

Comment: `pg_stat_user_tables` might not be populated if `track_activities` is disabled. Using the "official" API  such as `pg_tables` or `information_schema.table` is a **much** better choice.

Comment: side note to this old answer. It looks like information_schema.table only gives table names where you have some access permission. pg_tables allowed me to see names of all tables, even ones I did not have access to. (was useful in an interaction with an administrator)

Comment: @JerryD Good one!

Answer (score 0):

Yes one may obtain a list of user defined tables present in a database using a query like this:

```
SELECT
  table_name
FROM
  information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
```

Or

```
SELECT
  tablename
FROM
  pg_tables
WHERE schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
```

As reads in the [official](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG) docs:

> In addition to public and user-created schemas, each database contains a pg_catalog schema, which contains the system tables and all the built-in data types...

So it's a good target for filtering out the user-defined stuff from the builtin ones.
Stay aware that since its possible to define tables in schemas other than the public schema, relying on filtering of the results on table_schema as suggested by the other people and also in other places like the [google cloud's docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/information-schema-pg), is not a good option, because it may neglect the user-defined tables on the other builtin or user-defined schema.

Comment: This should be SELECT tablename, not table_name. Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html. Won't let me edit, says too many edits pending.