# pgAdmin and Postgresql relation does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have been working on a script in pgAdmin for a few days with an existing table. Now when I try to update the table from a command in my script I get a *relation does not exist* error. I can see the table in the object explorer tree and a right click to show the 100 rows of data works just fine. I also copied the *select * limit 100* query to a new tab in pgadmin and it works, but if I copy it to my existing script then it throws the *relation does not exist* error. The script also works in Dbeaver. Any idea what is going on?

I have just copied my script to a new tab in pgAdmin and it has started working. I have the solution but would like to know why it happened.

Comment: I don't think there is enough detail here to really say for sure. Possibly something as simple as you weren't connected to the (right) database at the time you tried to run the script.

Comment: maybe there is a character after he text run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730228/postgresql-query-to-list-all-table-names

Comment: It comes down to two possibilities 1) The relation does not exist because you are not connected to correct Postgres instance 2) Spelling/case issue, where the relation name was not properly written out. Without the actual query and complete error message it is not possible to be more definitive.

Comment: Use a different SQL tool, for example psql or Dbeaver. I've thrown away pgAdmin a long time ago...

Comment: can you share the exact error message?  `relation does not exist` isn't very descriptive, and usually Postgres does a good job providing an error message that helps to quickly identify and fix the problem